# Multiple Independent EAR deployment order

Tags: shell, ejb-3.0, jboss5.x

We are using jboss enterprise application platform 5 with EJB 3.0. In my application we are deploying 3 independent EAR's, no dependency (ear-1, ear-2, ear-3) and 1 war (war-1).

Can anyone please let me know 
1. how to configure the deployment order of ear's in JBoss [ear-3,ear-1,ear-2]. 
2. startup and shutdown of individual applications (ear's) using shell(.sh) script & not from JBoss admin console. i.e I want to start & stop only ear-2 using shell script

Comment: 1. Modified the topContextComparator bean in deployers.xml present default/conf/bootstrap to load the EAR's in an order.              2. The below link helped me to stop the ear via shell script but if it encouters the MDB as the first part then its failing to execute.                                                             http://nirvikalpa.wordpress.com/2010/08/25/start-stop-web-application-on-jboss-twiddle/ and http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-script/how-do-i-check-my-application-status-from-shell

Comment: Tested program to start and stop. Problem if we have MDB on top as displayed in JBOSS:J2EE JMX console.                                 export JBOSS_HOME="D:/jboss-as"
 export TWIDDLE="$JBOSS_HOME/bin/twiddle.sh"

 #./jbossApp.sh username password myEar.ear start/stop
  if test $# -lt 4
  then
        echo "Please enter the user,password,application war name and the start/stop op"
  else
        app=$($TWIDDLE -s 127.0.0.1 -u $1 -p $2 query 'jboss.j2ee:*' | grep $3)
        app=`echo $app |  sed 's/\r//g'`
        #doop=$($TWIDDLE -s 127.0.0.1 -u $1 -p $2 invoke jboss.j2ee:ear=$3,* $4  )
  fi